# which region opt for SES account in aws?

Tags: devops

I have application that will be deploy in qatar. But my server running on ohio region. Now i want to set SES account for server. By default ohio region is not supporting for SES. It shown three option
    Supported Regions
    US East (N. Virginia)
    EU (Ireland)
    US West (Oregon)
Which region should opt for my case? But my application will be deploy in Qatar?

Answer (score 0):

Ireland is by far the closest region out of those 3 to Qatar. Based on latency alone, I would choose Ireland.